# c++ : How to ask a file name and print char Array

Tags: c++

i am new in c++, i am working on a project, in case 1 i need to ask a file name from a user and if the file name is correct to it should print something like 6x5 character Array. I am totally confused that how to start. any single help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int x;
  string file;
  int temp;

  cout << "Welcome to Urban Heat Island Model" << endl;
  cout << "What would you like to do? " << endl;
  cout << "1. Load land cover file " << endl;
  cout << "2. Model Temperature Based on land cover" << endl;
  cout << "3. Exit " << endl;
  cin >> x;
  switch (x){
  case 1:
    cout << "What is the name of the file to import? " << endl;

    cin >> file;  

    break;
```

Comment: Why dont you just compare two strings

Comment: I suggest reading some tutorials instead. StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.

Comment: "print something like 6x5 character Array" What does that mean? What are you really supposed to print?

Comment: Random characters like A B C in rows and columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is a file that you want to open, you can try a file stream. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) is a good look at how to open a file for input and output. Just make sure to check if you can actually open the file before you try to read/write from/to it. You can do it with

```
if(inputFile.is_open())
{
    //your code here
}
```

If you just want to see if it is a valid file extension, check the last part of the string. 
If you have a list of file names, compare what they input and what you have to see if they are the same.

Comment: perfect thank you so much